# Number of Items in List MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, element

```
argument = [new_letter_A, new_letter_B, new_letter_C, new_letter_D, new_letter_E];
```

In Python, I can use len(argument) to find the number of items in the array above. Is there an easy way to accomplish the same thing in MATLAB? (I want this to return '5'.)Thank you.

Comment: Actually, each new_letter variable is a 1x703 vector, so the length won't work for this case... I want to return the number of letter arrays. @mathematician1975

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either store your vectors as rows and get the size of the first dimension

```
argument = [new_letter_A; new_letter_B; new_letter_C; new_letter_D; new_letter_E];
size(argument, 1)
```

Or you can store each vector as a cell in a cell array

```
argument = {new_letter_A, new_letter_B, new_letter_C, new_letter_D, new_letter_E};
length(argument)
```

One of the advantages of the second approach is that you can use `cellfun` to apply a function to each letter (for example, if you had a function which you were using to compress each letter...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `length` function:

`length(argument)`

Comment: `length` is a bad solution (and I'm 99% sure it will fail for this question) as it leaves you open to many errors you could avoid by being specific about which dimension you want the size of. I would ALWAYS recommend using `size` over `length`

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do this such as `numel`, `length` and `size`. MATLAB works with 2d arrays/matrices.

If your matrix is `n x m`:

- `numel` would be n*m
- `length` would be max(n, m)
- `size` would be n. You can use size(argument, 2) to get m.

In the case of 1-d array, they are all the same.